# How to call a function before refresh event, but not on exit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a situation where application will display a message to confirm with the user to go further or not, when he or she is trying to refresh the page. Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(VS.85).aspx it has same handler as close window event

Comment: You will get more answers if you provide some context. Show us the code you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your javascript code,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
       var e = e || window.event;
        //IE
        if (e) {
          e.returnValue = "prompt message";
        }
        else {
            //other browser
          return "prompt message";
        }
};
```

Comment: The above code is not working, presently i am using firefox in ubuntu

Comment: try setting only String message to window.onbeforeunload rather the function. like window.onbeforeunload = "Prompt message"; Also put the code in <head> tag.